# Child DIV does not stretch parent DIV

Tags: html

```
http://216.194.172.101/~culinare/index.php/terms-conditions-and-policies
```

The problem I'm having is pretty clear.  The DIV that shows the gray box with the T&C stretches beyond the parent DIV that contains it.  I've tried a number of variations in the CSS, and none of it seems to work.  What am I missing?

Comment: you have to post your code. links to sites aren't useful to future viewers who may have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Floating elements doesn't affect the size of the parent element. You can however make the parent contains the floating elements also, by using the `overflow` style:

```
.body_content { overflow: hidden; }
```

As the parent element doesn't have a specific height, the overflow style won't actually hide anything, it will just have the effect on the floating elements inside it.

Answer (score 1):

The div with the class .body_wrapper has left: right.
So you have to do the next:

```
.body_content {
   /* other styles */
   display: table;
}
```